Prevent users from injecting malware through images and videos
I'm developing a React App that allows users to upload images and videos.
The app is hosted on Firebase, uses Google Cloud Storage to store user's data and Cloud Functions as a serverless back-end.
When a user uploads an image, it goes to a Cloud Function through a busboy form data, gets checked for MIME type, gets compressed with shard and then it is stored to a public bucket behind a CDN.
If the image file is not a jpeg, png or webp, it is discarded.
The goal of this is to store the image on the bucket, get the CDN URL and provide it publicly.
The CDN URL is then used in img HTML elements as a src parameter.
At the same time, videos do follow a similar processing flow, but they're just uploaded from the client with TUS protocol after a signed URL for uploading to a Streaming API is created. They don't go through any particular validation or sanitization process, at this time.
The video is uploaded to a public CDN and a link to it is provided as a src parameter to a video HTML element with HLS enabled through hls.js.
At this point, my question is:
What if an user uploads some malware to my cloud functions, the file goes through and gets delivered through the CDN in those img element tags?
What about the videos?
From what I've read online, a way to avoid problematic scenarios is to run those files through a Docker container with ClamAV installed, check if the file can be accepted in the system and then proceed with the upload.
But this strategy protects the system from known malwares, not generic malicious code.
Am I safe with what I have in place right now? Do you still suggest to check the files with ClamAV?
Thanks!

How do you think malware can be delivered through an <img> tag?  And what do you mean by "generic malicious code"?  There is no magic way to identify malware, without checking for signatures, as ClamAV does.  If there were, ClamAV would use it.
